# How to create dataproc cluster so I can ssh into the workers later on?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, firewall, google-cloud-dataproc

Earlier whenever I used to create a dataproc cluster I would be able to SSH into the drivers and workers both. Now, I cannot. I get:

> Your connection will probably fail. VM is missing the firewall rule allowing TCP ingress traffic from 0.0.0.0/0 on port 22.

I have tried going to the VPC networks > Firewall and there is a firewall rule already there allowing ssh with :

[image]

and I added the cluster workers in the target tags:

[image]

**I never had to do this earlier and the workers were SSHed into without hassle**
How can I ssh into the workers in the dataproc clusters? I have full access to create new clusters, so if you can suggest the configuration with which I can create the new cluster to enable SSH into the workers that should solve my problem as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't add vm name to the target.

You first edit the worker you want to SSH into from the gcloud console > add a network tag > add the same network tag to the target of the ssh VPC firewall rule